# Exchange Integral and Derivative respect to a parameter of a Dirac delta-function

Tags: integration, differentiation, dirac-delta-distributions

I'm trying to solve the 6.2 problem of Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics textbook. At some point, to get the desired solution, I have to exchange a derivative applied to a Dirac delta-function with the integral operator:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R^3}} \frac{\partial \delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x_0}(t))}{\partial t}f(\mathbf{x})\,d^3x=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{\mathbb{R^3}} \delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x_0}(t))f(\mathbf{x})\,d^3x=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(\mathbf{x_0}(t))$$

Under which hypothesis can I do something like that (i.e. exchange the order of differentiation and integration)? I expect that known theorems of real analysis do not apply in this case, since the $\delta$ is not even a proper function.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic, I think it's a transversal question, since this result is needed to obtain the Feynman-Heaviside electromagnetical fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By **definition**, if $T$ is a distribution, then $$\langle \partial_x T, f \rangle := - \langle T, \partial_x f \rangle\tag{1}$$ for every test function $f=f(x)$ in $C_0^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ (or also $C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ if $T$ has compact support as the delta function). Here the derivative is just a bit more complicated. However, since the chain rule for taking the derivative of distributions composed with smooth functions is valid also for distributions (it is a general theorem) we have
$$\partial_t \delta(x-x_0(t)) = \frac{dx_0}{dt}|_{x_0}\cdot \nabla_{x_0} \delta(x-x_0(t)) = -\frac{dx_0}{dt}|_{x}\cdot \nabla_x \delta(x-x_0(t))\:. \tag{2}$$
As a consequence, **for every  function** $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$, applying (2),
$$\int \partial_t \delta(x-x_0(t)) f(x) d^nx = -\int \frac{dx_0}{dt}|_{x_0}\cdot \nabla_x \delta(x-x_0(t)) f(x) d^nx$$ $$=  -\frac{dx_0}{dt}|_{x_0}\cdot\int \nabla_x\delta(x-x_0(t)) f(x) d^nx  \:.$$
Applying (1)
$$\int \partial_t \delta(x-x_0(t)) f(x) d^nx = + \frac{dx_0}{dt}|_{x_0}\cdot  \int  \delta(x-x_0(t)) \nabla_x f(x) d^nx$$ $$=  \frac{dx_0}{dt}|_{x_0}\cdot \nabla_x f(x)|_{x_0(t)} = \frac{d}{dt}f(x_0(t))\:.$$

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks like a great answer, but it's not completely clear to me. Can you please explain better (2)? It looks like you used a sort of chain rule for distributions, but how does it works exactly? And why you could exchange x_0 with x in the gradient operator?

Comment: Yes, that is nothing but the standard chain rule which is assumed to be valid also for distributions if the internal function ($x_0$) is smooth. Regardind the second issue, I used the obvious fact that taking the derivative with respect to $x$ or to  $-x_0$ is the same as they appear summed in the argument. This is again an application of chain rule.

Comment: Thank you again. Just a last question: can the hypothesis on the smoothness of f(x) be relaxed? The particular function I'm working with has simple poles, so it's not a member of C^\infty(R^n).

Comment: If you want to stick to distribution theory you cannot relax that hypothesis (also using Hoermander's machinery to define multiplication of distribution, since the so called wavefront set of the delta is too large at the singular point). However the delta is also a measure, so in principle you may relax the smoothness requirement and construct an ad-hoc theory...

Comment: If the poles of your function are far from the singularity of $\delta$ you can simply ignore them...

Comment: Since this is the only way to obtain the Feynman-Heaviside electromagnetic fields (and I suppose that these fields are correct) I think I just have to ignore the poles and use the above property of the delta, even if it's not completely clear why it should be legitimate to ignore them. Thanks anyway, your help has been very helpful.

Comment: Well, you may use Hoermander's theory. More or less, the product of two distributions is well defined if their wavefront set satisfy a certain condition. This condition is true when the singular supports are disjoint. In your case this means that $x_0(t)$ is away from the poles of $f$. Here as standard in this procedures, I consider f itself as a distribution and I interpret $\int \delta(x-x_0) \nabla_x f(x) dx$ as  $\int \delta(x-x_0) \nabla_x f(x) \chi(x) dx$ where the test function $\chi$ satisfies $\chi(x)=1$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$.